# Is there any way to set rule for removing trailing comma using PHP-CS-Fixer?

Tags: php, coding-style, php-cs-fixer

I'm using **PHP-CS-Fixer** to set up linting in project. There is a rule `trailing_comma_in_multiline`. It lets you to check whether all multiple-lines arrays have trailing commas.

Is it possible to reverse this logic and check whether all multiple-lines arrays have NO trailing commas?

In other words I want this syntax to be valid:

```php
$data = [
    'First item',
    'Second item'
];
```

And this syntax to throw an error when checking with PHP-CS-Fixer:

```php
$data = [
    'First item',
    'Second item',
];
```

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing. Did you perhaps manage to find a working solution yet?

Comment: Unfortunately the problem is still unsolved

Comment: https://github.com/PHP-CS-Fixer/PHP-CS-Fixer/issues/6779

Comment: Just curious - WHY would you want something like this? Are you trying to format an old PHP version code?

Answer (score -1):

I believe that should work:

```
'trailing_comma_in_multiline' => ['elements' => []]
```

https://cs.symfony.com/doc/rules/control_structure/trailing_comma_in_multiline.html

Comment: Nope, this one isn't working, just checked. Thanks for answering anyway